# I am looking for a way to check if it gets response correctly in Fetch in JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fetch

I am looking for a way to check if it gets response correctly in Fetch in JS
I made the code below.
however, this error happens:

test?id=96&date=2021-08-13:282

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: responceData.forEach is not a function
> at

```
  let huu = fetch(url);
        tmp_char = "";
        huu.then(response => response.json()).then(
                responceData =>{
                    responceData.forEach(element => {
                        if(element['date'] != null ){
                           //CHECK
                        }
                    })
                }
           
        )
```

Response

```
        $a = Record::updateOrInsert(
            ['company_id' => (int) $request->id, 'date' => $request->date],
            ['numa'  => (int) $request->numa  ,'created_at' => now()]
        );
        Log::debug($a);
        return response()->json($request, '200', ['Content-Type' => 'application/json','Charset' => 'utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I would like to check if the `updateOrInsert` does its transaction.

Logs Laravel

> Argument 1 passed to Facade\Ignition\LogRecorder\LogMessage::__construct() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /Users/Developments/www/vendor/facade/ignition/src/LogRecorder/LogMessage.php on line 34 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Facade\Ignition\LogRecorder\LogMessage::__construct() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /Users//Developments/www//vendor/facade/ignition/src/LogRecorder/LogMessage.php on line 34 at /Users/Developments/www/vendor/facade/ignition/src/LogRecorder/LogMessage.php:21)

[image]

Comment: Open your DevTools, go to the network tab and check what the result is. Alternatively, do `console.log(responceData)` before the forEach.

Comment: I recommend, not returning an instance of `Request` as a response. Since you only want its data, use `$request->all()` instead.

Comment: Print `responceData`, to know what to send

Comment: console.log(responceData); 
It prints this.
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: some Errors changed.

Comment: Have you tried just removing `Log::debug($a)` completely? Or wrapping your code in a `try/catch`? I don't think your code is ever making it to the `return response() ...` section.

Comment: {date: "2021-08-06", id: "9", numa: "1100"}. returns after I erase Log::Debug($a)

Answer (score 0):

I think `responceData` is an Object, but forEach only works for Arrays, you could try and bypass this with

```
for(let [key, value, ...] of Object.entries(reponceData)){
// Do something
}
```

or return your data as an array